# jQuery parent().addClass() not working with hidden elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use

```
jQuery("#element-id").parent().addClass('some-class');
```

I have a structure something like this:

```
<div class="tab-container user-dash-tabs">
    <div class="tabs1">
        <ul class="shadetabs" id="countrytabs">
            <li class="poll"><a id="pillow-pack" rel="country2" href="javascript:;" class="selected"></a></li>
            <li class="bott"><a href="javascript:;" class="" id="bottles" rel="country1"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="cl"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="input-search" value="123" id="lubepack" name="lubepack">
    <p></p>
    <div class="cl"></div>

    <div class="tabcontent tab-content" id="country1" style="display: none;">
        <ul class="left-tab">
            <li title="water based" class="  add"><a class="  tab-pic7" id="tab-pic7-b" title="water based" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li title="silicone based"><a class="  tab-pic8" id="tab-pic8-b" title="silicon based" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li title="arousal"><a class="  tab-pic9" id="tab-pic9-b" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li title="flavored"><a class="  tab-pic10" id="tab-pic10-b" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li title="organic"><a class="  tab-pic11" id="tab-pic11-b" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li title="desensitizing"><a class="  tab-pic12" id="tab-pic12-b" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <div class="cl"></div>
        </ul>
        <div class="cl"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabcontent tab-content" id="country2" style="display: block;">
        <ul class="left-tab">
            <li class=" " title="water based"><a class="  tab-pic7" id="tab-pic7-p" title="water based" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li title="silicone based"><a class="  tab-pic8" id="tab-pic8-p" title="silicon based" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li title="arousal"><a class="  tab-pic9" id="tab-pic9-p" title="" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li title="flavored"><a id="tab-pic10-p" class="  tab-pic10" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li title="organic"><a id="tab-pic11-p" class="  tab-pic11" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li title="desensitizing"><a id="tab-pic12-p" class="  tab-pic12" href="javascript:;">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <div class="cl"></div>
        </ul>
        <div class="cl"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var countries=new ddtabcontent("countrytabs")
        countries.setpersist(true)
        countries.setselectedClassTarget("link") //"link" or "linkparent"
        countries.init()
    </script>

    <div class="cl"></div>
    <div class="search-box fl"><input type="text" id="name" class="input-search" name="name" value=""></div>
    <div class="cl"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, one `div` is hidden while the other is visible.

Whenever a link is clicked, a class of `add` should be applied to it's parent.

```
j("#" + id + "-p").parent().addClass("add");
j("#" + id + "-b").parent().addClass("add");
```

But, it's only adding the class to the `<li>` that is hidden. If I execute the same code from the Firebug console. It works fine.

I tried creating a method for doing this, still the same result. I am not sure why I am facing this kid of problem. If anyone has faced similar problem, please let me know.

Comment: Could you please post your HTML in a human readable format. I left my R2 unit at home.

Comment: you can use http://jsfiddle.net/ to post the example

Comment: I'm in a good mood this morning, so I formatted it for you, but please do this yourself in future.

Comment: @krister-andersson thank you, I was trying to edit the post when your suggestion poped up...

Comment: @krister-andersson, yes sure...

Comment: and @rory-mccrossan thanks to you for re-editing :)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because you are using `parent()` which only looks one level up the DOM tree from the current element, which in your case is the `li`. You need to use `closest()` instead, which will traverse it's way up the entire DOM until it finds the first element matching the selector provided.

With that in mind, the following should work for you:

```
j("#" + id + "-p").closest("DIV").addClass("add");
j("#" + id + "-b").closest("DIV").addClass("add");
```

Comment: @krister-andersson still the same result, I did `j("#" + id + "-p").closest("LI").addClass("add");` as I needed to apply class to the LI, but, exactly same result. I added an `alert('');` after the first line, to check if class is actually applying or not, it's applying, it's applying for a moement, then, **add** class is removed from the visible element...

Comment: so obviously there is some other code (that you did not show) that removes the class again. Please show all relevant code or (better) post a minimalistic example at jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com

Comment: ok, solved my problem, there was a click listner attached to `j('ul li')` to toggle class on click, in a different js file for different purpose... after that @krister-andersson soultion worked like charm...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
j("#" + id + "-p").parents("DIV.tabcontent").addClass("add");
j("#" + id + "-b").parents("DIV.tabcontent").addClass("add");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']").parents(".hidden-ul").css("display", "block");
        $("a[href='" + window.location.pathname + "']").parent("li").addClass("select");
    });
```